# Python 3.0+ Calculating Mode

Tags: python

I have written a program to calculate the most often occurring number. This works great unless you have 2 most occurring numbers in a list such as 7,7,7,9,9,9. For that I wrote in:

```
if len(modeList) > 1 and modeList[0] != modeList[1]:
    break
```

but then I encounter other problems like a set of number with 7,9,9,9,9. What do I do. Below is my code that will calculate one Mode.

```
list1 = [7,7,7,9,9,9,9]
numList=[]
modeList=[]
finalList =[]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for k in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i] == list1[k]:
            numList.append(list1[i])
numList.append("EOF")
w = 0
for w in range(len(numList)):
    if numList[w] == numList[w + 1]:
        modeList.append(numList[w])
    if numList[w + 1] == "EOF":
        break
w = 0
lenMode = len(modeList)
print(lenMode)
while lenMode > 1:
    for w in range(lenMode):
        print(w)
        if w != lenMode - 1:
            if modeList[w] == modeList[w + 1]:
                finalList.append(modeList[w])
                print(w)
    lenFinal = len(finalList)
    modeList = []
    for i in range(lenFinal):
        modeList.append(finalList[i])
    finalList = []
    lenMode = len(modeList)
```

and then

```
print(modeList)
```

We have not learned counters but I would be open to it if someone could explain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/collections.html#counter-objects) for this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([7,9,9,9,9])
>>> max(c.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
9
```

This is really rather simple. All it does is count how many times each value appears in the list, and then selects the element with the highest count.

Comment: so could you explain the collections, counter key and lambda. The list I wrote is just an example. I am reading the numbers from a file into a list. And then finding the mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`statistics.mode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode) for this.  If there is more than one mode, it will raise an exception.  If you need to handle multiple modes (it's not clear to me whether that's the case), you probably want to use a `collections.Counter` object as suggested by NPE.